# Form inputs with onchange() callbacks update on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with some input fields and all those fields have `onchange` triggered callbacks (which can be different depending on the field).

My problem is that when the form is submitted the focus is still on the last modified field and the `onchange` callback is not called for this field, which can lead to submit wrong values.

I am looking for a way to force the triggering on the `onchange` event for the last field modified but I can't determine which element it is from my `submit` function.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: why can't you revalidate them all? it's safer anyway... unless it's server side validation, I really wouldn't worry about performance in cases like this.

Comment: There can be hundreds of fields in the form, revalidating each form does not sound like the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$focused_element = $(':focus');
if($focused_element.is('input')){
  $focused_element.trigger('change');
}
```

Comment: You've got the idea of what I was looking for. I'm trying it.